# Invalid Postback occurring?

Tags: asp.net

I keep getting this error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I have registered the ClientScriptMagner.Regis.... but still nothing.

I have dropdownlist's in a control and when my form is submitted, this happens.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What code you have written is Page_load event?

Comment: you have to show your code!!!

Comment: Take a look at article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitsh/archive/2007/07/31/why-i-get-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-errors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is happening because you are changing anything behind the scene. might be to use cascading dropdowns or something that is changing the original state of the page.

Not exactly the perfect solution but it works:

in your aspx Page directive to false entry EnableEventValidation change.

```
EnableEventValidation = "false"
```

Hope that Helps